# How to debug Scheduler pallet not making the scheduled call?

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet

I have integrated scheduller pallet into my node, trying to test it running the node and using polkadot js. All compiles. The scheduled task event is printed to the explorer, but when the block used as execution time arrives nothing happens. What is the better way to check what part is failing?

The following is the code that schedule the task in the pallet code and the config in runtime lib:

```rust
if T::Scheduler::schedule_named(
            (POLLS_ID, poll.currency, poll_id).encode(),
            DispatchTime::At(end),
            None,
            63,
            frame_system::RawOrigin::Root.into(),
            Call::enact_poll_end { poll_currency: poll.currency, poll_id }.into(),
        )
        .is_err()

impl pallet_scheduler::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeOrigin = RuntimeOrigin;
    type PalletsOrigin = OriginCaller;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    type MaximumWeight = (); // No weight limit. Modify this to set a limit.
    type ScheduleOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type MaxScheduledPerBlock = ConstU32<100>;
    type WeightInfo = ();
    type OriginPrivilegeCmp = EqualPrivilegeOnly;
    type Preimages = ();
}
```

Comment: Try setting `MaximumWeight` to `Weight::max_value()` by adding a new `parameter_type!` for it like `MaxSchedulerWeight`.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi It worked. Thanks a lot. Do you know what was happening? type MaximumWeight = () means to give no weight to the execution or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheduler has `MaximumWeight` weight available each block to process tasks. Setting it to `()` means that it has zero weight available and therefore does nothing.
You can take a look at the [Polkadot runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/ac0d5ab5448303dc834d2afca6c29c4d93920859/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L178) on how to configure it with a better value. For example 80% of the total block limit.